# Error "'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x134d0a3c0'"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, apple-push-notifications

I'm implementing `Apple Push Notification Services` on my app. After getting the notification, I want to get the information and add it into a uitableview. I followed this [*Pushbots* tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9zw34QbYRx5oq8jZ-wdfHA4ww5K2O_jq) like this:

In the `AppDelegate.m` file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [Pushbots sharedInstanceWithAppId:@"--my app id--"];
    [[Pushbots sharedInstance] receivedPush:launchOptions];
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // This method will be called everytime you open the app
    // Register the deviceToken on Pushbots
    [[Pushbots sharedInstance] registerOnPushbots:deviceToken];
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Notification Registration Error %@", [error userInfo]);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    //Handle notification when the user click it while app is running in background or foreground.
    [[Pushbots sharedInstance] receivedPush:userInfo];
    NSString *msg = [userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"];
    NSLog(@"Push Notification:%@",msg);

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:msg forKey:@"ReceivedNotifications"];
}
```

In my `ViewController.m`:

```
@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *notifTableView;
@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *notif;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    notif = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ReceivedNotifications"];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [notif count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [notif objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

However, I keep getting an error at the console:

```
[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x134d0a3c0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x134d0a3c0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x180f45900 0x1805b3f80 0x180f4c61c 0x180f495b8 0x180e4d68c 0x100091b28 0x185f8931c 0x185f89484 0x185f787e8 0x185f8dfb0 0x185d2308c 0x185c33778 0x183642b2c 0x18363d738 0x18363d5f8 0x18363cc94 0x18363c9dc 0x1836360cc 0x180efc588 0x180efa32c 0x180e296a0 0x185ca6580 0x185ca0d90 0x100092a1c 0x1809ca8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This is my `main.m` file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message clearly reveals that the receiver of `objectAtIndex` is an `NSDictionary` object.

It is created from the `aps` object of a push notification which is indeed always a dictionary and saved in user defaults with the key `ReceivedNotifications`.

You have to parse the dictionary to extract the information you want to display.

PS: Do not use `valueForKey` – which is a KVC method with special behavior –  to get an object from a dictionary. The designated method is `objectForKey`.

Comment: How do I change it into an array object?

Comment: That depends on what you're going to accomplish. The standard `aps` dictionary contains the keys `alert` and `badge`. `alert` itself is a dictionary with several keys and `badge` is an integer. Enumerate the dictionaries and get the values and keys you need. Put it into an array.

Comment: Do you have a sample code or something? I'm trying to get the text of the notification that the phone received to put into a table.

Comment: Read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html to see the structure of the payload. Then it's just a subscription chain `userInfo["aps"]["alert"]["title"] or ["body"]` . Of course you have to cast the intermediate partial results to something meaningful to satisfy the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

=> Make sure that you really have an array on your hands when you call objectAtIndex: